# How can I detect name collision of local classes with global ones in JS or TS using ESLint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

In JavaScript, you can define a class with a name like `Node` or `Attr`. I think it might lead a confusion, as there is also a global constructor function with the same names. I believe linting is ESLint's job, but I couldn't figure out how to configure it to detect it. Neither `no-shadow` nor `no-redeclare` seems not working for this kind of redeclaration or shadowing. `typescript-eslint` couldn't detect it either.

Is there a way to prevent shadowing of global classes?

Edit: `no-shadow` with `{ builtinGlobals: true }` doesn't do a trick. It works only for names like `Object` or `undefined`.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow - pass an option object to no-shadow with builtinGlobals set to true.

Comment: @pascalpuetz Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, it seems to work only for the ES built-in names.

Comment: Something seems not be right. I tried this out in the playground and `no-shadow: ["error", { "builtinGlobals": true }]` seems to do the trick there. You have to be sure to have the disallowed globals in your environment though (e.g. `"env": { "browser": true }` to disallow `window`). Here the link to the playground: https://cutt.ly/UkkwUI6 (mind, I had to run this through a URL shortener since it was too long for a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this can be achieved by using the `no-shadow` rule. By default, the rule does not check the built-in types (e.g. `window`, `Node` or `Attr`), but it can be configured to do so by setting the option `builtinGlobals` to true, like this:

```json
no-shadow: ["error", { "builtinGlobals": true }]
```

This now tells ESLint to check if any variables shadows any name that is available in the global scope - but you have to configure which ones are actually available, since ESLint does not know that by itself. You can do that by setting the correct environments through the `env` configuration:

```
"env": { 
    "browser": true
}
```

I configured a [small example in the ESLint Playground Demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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) to showcase this.

Comment: Suggest using `@typescript-eslint/no-shadow` instead, as it's made for typescript. https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-shadow.md